# clickable map of dots

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I wanted to make a 3 x 3 map with dots as their location. when you click a dot then it will change the path that you are using, i.e the line will be changed to that route. This being the color of it as well as the line position does anyone know how? This is what I had already. Now im confused of how to make a function that would implement this functionality.

```
import React from "react";

import styled from 'styled-components';
import { scaleLinear } from "d3-scale";

var mapStyles = { position: "relative" };
var svgStyles = { position: "absolute", top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 };

function Map({ width, height, nodes }) {
  var xScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, width]);
  var yScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, height]);



return (
 <div id="map" style={mapStyles}>

  <svg
    style={svgStyles}
    width={width}
    height={height}
    viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${height}`}
  >
    {links.map((link, i) => (
      <line
        key={i}
        x1={xScale(nodes[link.s].x)}
        x2={xScale(nodes[link.d].x)}
        y1={yScale(nodes[link.s].y)}
        y2={yScale(nodes[link.d].y)}
        strokeWidth={5}
        stroke={
          nodes[link.s].done === true && nodes[link.d].done
            ? "#CBFF5B"
            : "grey"
        }
      />
    ))}
    {nodes.map((node, i) => (
      <circle
        key={i}
        cx={xScale(node.x)}
        cy={yScale(node.y)}
        r="20"
        fill={node.done === true ? "#CBFF5B" : "grey"}
      />
    ))}
  </svg>
</div>
  );
}

var nodes = [
  { x: 10, y: 10},
  { x: 10, y: 30, done: true },
    { x: 10, y: 50, done: true },
    { x: 50, y: 10, done: true},
    { x: 50, y: 30} ,
    { x: 50, y: 50 },
    { x: 90, y: 10 },
    { x: 90, y: 30 },
    { x: 90, y: 50 }
];

var links = [{ s: 3, d: 1 }, { s: 1, d: 2 }];

export const NodeMap = () => {

const avg = () => {
    var elem = [ 0, 1, 2,]
    var sum = 0;
    for( var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++ ){
        sum += parseInt( elem[i], 10 ); //don't forget to add the base
    }

    return sum/3;
}



return (
    <Container>
            <div className="App">
      <Map width={666} height={1340} nodes={nodes} links={links} />
    </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: How do you want to change a connection? Click on a node to select and then change the connection to a new node. Or do you want to just click on a node and it should change the closest connection to the new location?

Comment: I've started coding [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-merkle-bctmy?file=/src/App.js) - it's not finished yet because I don't know how it should behave.

Comment: To click on a node to select and then change the connection to a new node.